# React Native update placeholder of TextInput

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change the placeholder of a TextInput with setState. But this does not seem to work.

```
render() {
   return (
      <TextInput 
           placeholder={this.state.useThisPlaceholder}  
      />
   );
}
```

If i try the above code with value attribute instead of placeholder it works fine. Is this behaviour not allowed or am I missing something ?

Thank you.

**Update**

```
 constructor() {

    super();

    this.formSections = {
        first:{
            fields:['username', 'password', 'confirm password'],
            buttonText:'Next',
            buttonAction:() => this._loadNext()
        },
        second:{
            fields:['first name', 'last name', 'email'],
            buttonText:'Register',
            buttonAction:() => alert('registering with the server')
        }
    }

    this.state = {
        currentFormSection:'first'
    }

}

_loadNext() {

    this.setState({
        currentFormSection:'second'
    });

}

render() {

    return (

        <View
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <TextInput
                placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[0]}
                style={styles.textInput}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
            />
            <TextInput 
                placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[1]}
                style={styles.textInput}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
            />

            <TextInput 
                placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[2]}
                style={styles.textInput}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,1)"
            />

            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.formBtn}
                onPress={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].buttonAction}
            >
                <Text style={styles.formBtnText}>
                    {this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].buttonText}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

    );
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve here is using same text inputs for different form fields. Here the placeholder updates to blank. After setState the input field is blank with no value and no text. But if I type something to the input and erase it all, the updated placeholder appears.

Comment: this will work. placeholder is shown when there is no value given for textinput

Comment: @Sujan I have posted my code. You can also tell your requirement where you want to change the placeholder after that I can try according to you.

Comment: @Deepak and Vicky i thought it was supposed to work to but in my project it is behaving weirdly. I've updated with the real code, am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @Sujan Updated your code. Please check that. I have tried, it's working fine at my end. In case you need any change, let me know

Comment: @sujan Updated. Try one more time . Just copy and paste. It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code one more time. Just copy and paste this code. Firstly it shows **username, password, confirm password and Next** button. When you enter text in TextInputs and click on Next Button then It shows **firstname, lastname, email and Register** Button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
            super();
            this.formSections = {
                first:{
                    fields:['username', 'password', 'confirm password'],
                    buttonText:'Next',
                    buttonAction:() => this._loadNext()
                },
                second:{
                    fields:['first name', 'last name', 'email'],
                    buttonText:'Register',
                    buttonAction:() => alert('registering with the server')
                }
            }
            this.state = {
                valueOfFirstInput:'',
                valueOfSecondInput:'',
                valueOfThirdInput:'',
                currentFormSection:'first'
            }
        }

        _loadNext() {

            this.setState({
                valueOfFirstInput:'',
                valueOfSecondInput:'',
                valueOfThirdInput:'',
                currentFormSection:'second'
            });
        }

        render() {

            return (

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput style={{width:200}}
                        placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[0]}
                        value = {this.state.valueOfFirstInput}
                        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ valueOfFirstInput: value })}
                    />
                    <TextInput style={{width:200}}
                        placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[1]}
                        value = {this.state.valueOfSecondInput}
                        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ valueOfSecondInput: value })}
                    />

                    <TextInput style={{width:200}}
                        placeholder={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].fields[2]}
                        value = {this.state.valueOfThirdInput}
                       onChangeText={value => this.setState({ valueOfThirdInput: value })}
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.formBtn}
                        onPress={this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].buttonAction}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.formBtnText}>
                            {this.formSections[this.state.currentFormSection].buttonText}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

            );
        }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#abcdef',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

Try one more time. May be it helps you.

Comment: I really appreciate you doing this much but sadly this still does not work on my device, I will check with other devices to see if its just my phone.

Comment: I have now checked this with 2 android devices and on both of them it still does not work.

Comment: @sujan Updated. Try one more time . Just copy and paste. It is working fine.

Comment: did copy and paste as well ... checked on both devices , still not working.

Comment: @sujan Can you please tell me what is the output of my code ?

Comment: The behaviour of your code is as same as my code. The placeholder is still not updated.